# Custom code for wp product page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to make a text field option on product page of wp website. The scenario is when the customer clicks on how quantity he requires, what I need is to show the corresponding text fields for it. Like 2 text fields for 2 quantity. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following -

- Have a text field that takes that number as input.
- Have a button which when clicked triggers a javascript function `create_fields`
- Insert logic for creating text fields according to the number input.

Use the docs - https://api.jquery.com/ to learn how you would accomplish the above in code.

Comment: Thanks @bitsapien I'll try that!